# I need to change the style of an element of my Array in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, http

I need to Style:"text-decoration: line-through" on the second element of my array, how can i do that? 
I tryed with CSS and with [ngStyle] but nothing worked.
My array is taken from an HTTP get request, but i don't think it change a lot.
In my TypeScript file i have the array of object but if i try to change the style there, nothing works.

```
TypeScript:
export class TypeObjectComponent implements OnInit {
  object: Objects[];
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private service: ObjectService
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getType().subscribe(data => {
      this.object= data;
    })
  }

  HTML:
  <div class="form-group">
            <label for="typeO" ><b>Type</b></label>
            <select value="E" class="form-control" id="single" name="type">
              <option [ngStyle]="{'text-decoration': line-through}" *ngFor="let Objects of object; index as i">
              {{i}} - {{ Objects.type}}
            </option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: There is no `ngStyle` being used in your code.

Comment: try with class add more class and write css for it and change just class

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that, in your `[ngStyle]`, you need quotes around the value `line-through` because, in that context, that's a JavaScript object value, not a CSS value.

That change should successfully apply `text-decoration: line-through` to your `option` elements.

However, that will probably not accomplish your goal of displaying your second item with a line through it (if I understand your goal correctly) because the `option` element within a `select` is a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element), so even with that style applied, the element will not display with a line-through. From MDN:

> In CSS, a replaced element is an element whose representation is outside the scope of CSS; they're external objects whose representation is independent of the CSS formatting model...The position of the replaced element can be affected using CSS, but not the contents of the replaced element itself.

So if you need custom styling on the dropdown options, you'll probably need to use something other than a `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class on your 2nd element using the index value you have defined and write whatever styles you want to in your css file based on that class. For example see that edited part in html.

```
 TypeScript:
    export class TypeObjectComponent implements OnInit {
      object: Objects[];
      constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private service: ObjectService
      ) { }
      ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getType().subscribe(data => {
          this.object= data;
        })
      }

  HTML:
  <div class="form-group">
            <label for="typeO" ><b>Type</b></label>
            <select value="E" class="form-control" id="single" name="type">
              <option [ngClass]="{'line-through': i === 1}" *ngFor="let Objects of object; let i=index;">
              {{i}} - {{ Objects.type}}
            </option>
            </select>
        </div>

IN YOUR CSS:
.line-though{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```